# If $a_n$ is prime then $n$ is prime too

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

> Given sequence $(a_n)$ : $a_1=1, a_2=4, a_3=15, a_n=15a_{n-2}-4a_{n-3}$.
>   Prove that if $a_n$ is prime then $n$ is prime too.

It is easy to prove that $a_n=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ and $a_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n-(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{2\sqrt{3}}$ but I don't know what I should do now.

Comment: It helps if you explain what you have attempted and any ideas you may have on the problem. This may be why you are getting downvotes

Comment: certainly post several consecutive values of the sequence. The degree three recurrence is unusual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your computations are correct, we prove by contradiction. Assume that $n$ is composite, i.e. $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$ such that $n=ab$.

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n-(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{2\sqrt{3}}\\\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^{ab}-(2-\sqrt{3})^{ab}}{2\sqrt{3}}\\\\
&=\frac{\left[(2+\sqrt{3})^a-(2-\sqrt{3})^a\right]\left[(2+\sqrt{3})^b+\ldots+(2-\sqrt{3})^b\right]}{2\sqrt{3}}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Consider the factors in the numerator. One of them is natural and the other should be divisible by $2\sqrt 3$. Since $a,b>1$, you get that both these natural factors of $a_n$ are greater than $1$, making $a_n$ composite.